# App 'category' doesn't provide model 'category' when using abstract base classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Django==3.0.6**

**Github:** https://github.com/Kifsif/pcask

**/category/models.py**

```
class Category(CommentMixin,
               TitleMixin,
               SlugMixin,
               models.Model):
    pass

from category.models import Category
```

**/post/models.py**

```
class Post(TitleMixin,
           SlugMixin,
           DescriptionMixin,
           models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 related_name='blog_posts')
```

The database has been dropped and recreated. All migrations have been deleted. 
In settings.py 'post' and 'category' are added.

When making migrations:

```
(venv) michael@michael:~/PycharmProjects/pcask/pcask$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 168, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 129, in _detect_changes
    self.new_apps = self.to_state.apps
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 209, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 279, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field post.Post.category was declared with a lazy reference to 'category.category', but app 'category' doesn't provide model 'category'.
```

My mixin classes look like:

```
class CommentMixin():
    comment = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Could you help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: I have tried 'category.Category', the same error.

Comment: Edited the initial question. And added link to GitHub.

Comment: Alasdair, yes, my fault. Thank you. I'll add them to gitignore.

The problem is solved. The problem is really in mixins. Namely it is that mixins don't inherit from models.Model. I added inheritance, now it is working. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your mixin classes inherit `models.Model`, for example:

```
class CommentMixin(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

You can then remove `models.Model` from your child classes, for example:

```
class Category(CommentMixin,
               TitleMixin,
               SlugMixin,
               ):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make python understand that your directories are packages, you should add `__init__.py` in them.

```
├── pcask
├── __init__.py
│   ├── category
├── |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── post
├──     ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
```

Comment: Inits have been generated by startapp script. Anyway, how can it help? Your logic seems to be about importing, But importing is Ok.